# Typing speed to become a coder for a company

Tags: coding-style, typing

I know it may be a lame question, But i have to ask it what should be the minimum typing speed necessary to code for a company.

Currently I have a typing speed of 30 words per minute. Would it suffice?

Comment: I have never ever seen an employer worry about that. When you code, most of the time you are reading and thinking. Furthermore, trying to type quickly when coding is very dangerous... Besides, writing words is very different to writing code. Having a high WPM rate is justo useful for writing comments quickly. :P

Comment: I would strongly suggest that a firm grasp of programming, including algorithms, data structures, analysis of performance tradeoffs, and the ability to think logically through problem/design scenarios is infinitely more useful/important than merely being able to push a bunch of buttons quickly...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a person's physical skill, rather than a direct programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You Must

•be able to type without looking at the keyboard.

•not be thinking about where which key is which on the keyboard (most of the time).

•be free to watch what is happening on the screen as you type/mouse around.

### You May

•be able to type in both Qwerty and Dvorak, but it is annoying when pairing and I try to use your keyboard and it is in Dvorak. ;-)

### I Will

•go mental if I have to watch and wait for you to hunt and peck with your two pointiest fingers.

•be fine if you don't bring up that I can't type quite as fast as you can.

### Please

•learn the key-bindings in the software you use .

•do not use the mouse to navigate to the edit menu to cut and paste.

•do not click the go button in your web browser when you just finished typing in the url.

•find out how to move more than one character at a time when using a console/terminal

•on unix learn what the readline library is and learn to recognize its presence in the different tools you already use.

When driving a car that has a standard transmission, one should not have to look down to find where in the gear box you are going to shift gears to. It may be acceptable to look to find reverse though.

I don't think you need to be a fast typist, just a competent one.